# DB/SQL best practice: Validate data before insert, or TRY to insert and use error message

Tags: sql, postgresql, software-design

This is a general software engineering principle question. Which is "better":

- to validate that your data is correct *before* inserting it into the database, or
- to *try* to insert, and then interpret the error message if it doesn't succeed.

Ok. Example: You want to add a new movie to your database. A movie must have a unique name. Do you try to insert it, and then let the `unique constraint` catch it. -**OR**- do you first do a SELECT-query to check if such a movie already exists?

A movie also belongs to a genere. Do you do a select query first to see if the genre exists in the database, or do you let the foreign key constraint "catch"/validate it?

The problem with checking beforehand is ofc the race condition -- some other thread can insert a movie with that title while you're validating everything -- so there's really no guarantee in a multithreaded system. On the other hand, the error message you get back from (Postgre)SQL is usually in plain English, so it's not structured data (like e.g. json), so it requires to **PARSE** it in order to understand what went wrong so you generate a non-technincal error message to your end user.

Is there any best pracitice on this? This has got to be a very common dilemma?

Comment: As long as there's only single row operations the checking is normally done by the DBMS. But when you do DML on a larger number of rows, e.g. INSERT/SELECT, you better go with checking beforehand. Otherwise most DBMSes only return "there was an error" but don't tell which row failed.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to have the database do the work to check for uniqueness.

There are two main reasons why.  First, if you need for the name to be unique, you want the database to maintain this constraint on the data.  So, the database is going to check *anyway*.  Doing an additional check duplicates effort, so just decreases performance.

Second, in a multi-threaded environment, you can have race conditions.  There is a lag between any check that you make in your code and the `insert` statement.  Another thread could be inserting the same value at the same time.  You can get around this lag by using transactions, but that decreases performance.